# Troubleshooting compile time circular linked list errors

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linked-list

Okay, so I'm getting these errors upon compile with gcc:

```
prelab6.h: In function âinsertHeadCircularâ:
prelab6.h:45: error: incompatible types in assignment
prelab6.h:46: error: incompatible types in assignment
prelab6.c: At top level:
prelab6.c:41: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
prelab6.c:41: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
prelab6.c:41: error: conflicting types for âprintInOrderâ
prelab6.h:81: error: previous definition of âprintInOrderâ was here
prelab6.c:42: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
prelab6.c:42: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
prelab6.c:42: error: conflicting types for âprintReverseâ
prelab6.h:112: error: previous definition of âprintReverseâ was here
```

I've tried and tried, but to no avail to fix these errors. Thanks for any and all help.

Here's my .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "my.h"

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{

char firstname[100];
char lastname[100];
int monthsEmployed;

FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if (fptr == NULL)
    printf ("Incorrect file reading!");

if (argc != 2)
    printf ("Incorrect number of arguments!");


employeeInfo *insert;
insert = malloc(sizeof(employeeInfo));
employeeList *head;
head = NULL;


while(!feof(fptr))
{   
    fscanf (fptr, "%100s %100s %d", firstname, lastname, &monthsEmployed);

    strcpy(insert->firstname, firstname);
    strcpy(insert->lastname, lastname); 
    insert->monthsEmployed = monthsEmployed;

    head = insertHeadCircular(head, insert);
}
}

printInOrder(head); // display the linked list
printReverse(head); // display the linked list in reverse
```

And my .h file (note things are commented out because I tried things differently with no results):

```
typedef struct employeeInfo{
        char firstname[100];
        char lastname[100];
        int monthsEmployed;
}employeeInfo;

//Struct containing pointers to the next and previous used to make a circular linked list 
typedef struct list{
                employeeInfo emp;
                struct list *next;
                struct list *previous;
}employeeList;

employeeList *insertHeadCircular(employeeList *head, employeeInfo *emp);
void printInOrder(employeeList head);
void printReverse(employeeList head);

employeeList *insertHeadCircular(employeeList *head, employeeInfo *emp)
{
    employeeList *theprevious = head;
    employeeList *current;
    employeeList *thenext = head;
    current = malloc(sizeof(employeeList));
    employeeInfo *employee;

    if(thenext==NULL)
    {
        current->next = current;
        current->previous = current;
    }

    else
    {
        current->next = thenext;
        thenext->previous = current;

        while(theprevious->next != thenext)
        {
            theprevious = theprevious->next;
        }
        current->previous = theprevious;
        theprevious->next = current;
    }

    current->emp = (employeeInfo *)malloc(sizeof(employeeInfo));
    employee = current->emp;
    employee = malloc(sizeof(employeeInfo));
    strcpy(employee->firstname, emp->firstname);
    strcpy(employee->lastname, emp->lastname);
    employee->monthsEmployed = emp->monthsEmployed;

    /*
    employeeList *newcell, *first = head;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        newcell = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        strcpy(newcell->firstname, emp->firstname);
        strcpy(newcell->lastname, emp->lastname);
        newcell->monthsEmployed = emp->monthsEmployed;
        return newcell;
    }

    while(head->next != first)
    {
        head = head->next;
    }

    newcell = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    head->next = newcell;
    strcpy(newcell->firstname, emp->firstname);
    strcpy(newcell->lastname, emp->lastname);
    newcell->monthsEmployed = emp->monthsEmployed;
    newcell->next = first;
    */
return current;
}


void printInOrder(employeeList head)
{
    /*employeeInfo *first = head;

    if (head == NULL)
        {
        printf("The circularly linked list is empty!\n");
        return;
        }

        do
        {

        printf("%s %s %d\n", emp.firstname, emp.lastname, head.monthsEmployed);

        head = head->next;
        } while(head != first);
*/
    /*employeeInfo current = head;
    employeeInfo start = head;
    int loop = 0;
    printf("--------------\n");
    while(current != start || loop==0)
    {
    loop++;
    printf("Employee: %s %s\nMonths Employed: %d", current->firstname, current->lastname, current->monthsEmployed);
    printf("--------------\n");
    current=current->next;
    }*/
}

void printReverse(employeeList head)
{/*
    employeeList current = head
    employeeInfo start = head
    int theloop=0;
    printf("--------------\n");
    while(current! = start || loop==0)
    {
    loop++;
    printf("Employee: %s %s\nMonths Employed: %d", current->firstname, current->lastname, current->monthsEmployed);
    printf("--------------\n");
    current=current->previous;
    }*/
}
```

**EDITED PROGRAM**

Error:

```
file.c: In function âmainâ:
file.c:37: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of âinsertHeadCircularâ
```

The .c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "file.h"

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{

char firstname[100];
char lastname[100];
int monthsEmployed;

FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if (fptr == NULL)
    printf ("Incorrect file reading!");

if (argc != 2)
    printf ("Incorrect number of arguments!");


employeeInfo *insert;
insert = malloc(sizeof(employeeInfo));
employeeList *head;
head = NULL;


while(!feof(fptr))
{   
    fscanf (fptr, "%100s %100s %d", firstname, lastname, &monthsEmployed);

    strcpy(insert->firstname, firstname);
    strcpy(insert->lastname, lastname); 
    insert->monthsEmployed = monthsEmployed;

    head = insertHeadCircular(head, insert);
}

printInOrder(head); // display the linked list
printReverse(head); // display the linked list in reverse
}
```

The .h:

```
typedef struct employeeInfo{
    char firstname[100];
    char lastname[100];
    int monthsEmployed;
}employeeInfo;

typedef struct list{
    employeeInfo emp;
    struct list *next;
    struct list *previous;
}employeeList;
    typedef employeeList *listnode;

employeeList *insertHeadCircular(employeeList *head, employeeInfo emp);
void printInOrder(employeeList *head);
void printReverse(employeeList *head);



employeeList *insertHeadCircular(employeeList *head, employeeInfo emp)
{
    listnode newPtr;
    listnode firstPtr;
    listnode tempPtr;

    newPtr = (employeeList *)malloc(sizeof(employeeList));

    strcpy(newPtr->emp.firstname, emp.firstname);
    strcpy(newPtr->emp.lastname, emp.lastname);
    newPtr->emp.monthsEmployed = emp.monthsEmployed;

    if(head == NULL)
    {   
        newPtr->next = newPtr;
        newPtr->previous = newPtr;
        head = newPtr;
        firstPtr = newPtr;

    }
    else
    {
        tempPtr = firstPtr;
        newPtr->next = tempPtr;
        tempPtr->previous = newPtr;

        newPtr->previous = head;
        head->next = newPtr;
        firstPtr = newPtr;
    }
    return head;
}
void printInOrder(employeeList *head)
{
        listnode currentPtr = head;
        do
    {
            printf("%s %s %d\n",currentPtr->emp.firstname, currentPtr->emp.lastname, currentPtr->emp.monthsEmployed);
        currentPtr= currentPtr->previous;
    }
    while(currentPtr !=head);
}
void printReverse(employeeList *head)
{
        listnode currentPtr = head->next;
        do        
    {
        printf("%s %s %d\n",currentPtr->emp.firstname, currentPtr->emp.lastname, currentPtr->emp.monthsEmployed);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
    }
    while(currentPtr != head->next);        
}
```

Comment: you have code in your .h file???

Comment: he's probably solving a lab assignment.. :) and added the code in the h file :)

Comment: @Flunkie: homework tag? where are the lines in the code where the error happen?

Comment: Note that "while (!feof(fptr))" is the wrong way to read a file. You should use "while (fscanf(....) ...." instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your `insertHeadCircular()` function, you treat the `emp` member of `employeeList` as though it were an `employeeInfo *`.  For example, you declare:

```
employeeInfo *employee;
```

but then later do this:

```
employee = current->emp;
```

However, your `employeeList` type contains an instance of `employeeInfo`, not a pointer to one:

```
typedef struct employeeInfo{
        char firstname[100];
        char lastname[100];
        int monthsEmployed;
}employeeInfo;
/* ... */
typedef struct list{
                employeeInfo emp;    /* see? Not a pointer. */
                struct list *next;
                struct list *previous;
}employeeList;
```

So basically you need to correct your code so that you stop assigning a structure to a pointer, and instead assign the *address of* the structure to the pointer.

Most likely your `printInOrder()` and `printReverse()` functions should take `employeeList *` arguments, rather than `employeeList` ones, as well... and you should check the code you use for them to make sure you don't confuse the two anywhere.

It's also a good idea to define your functions somewhere other than the header file, such as in a separate `.c` source file.  The header file should just contain function prototypes, macros, and other declarations that may be needed for other source files; you don't need the function bodies in there, since the linker can find them in the object files created from your other sources.  Defining functions in header files like that will cause endless headaches when the header file is `#include`ed by more than one file.

---

The error you get with your updated code, `file.c:37: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of âinsertHeadCircularâ` is pointing out that the type of argument you're passing to `insertHeadCircular()` isn't the type you gave in its declaration -- which is true.  You've declared and defined that function to take an `employeeInfo` as its second argument:

```
employeeList *insertHeadCircular(employeeList *head, employeeInfo emp)
```

...but in `main()` you pass it a pointer instead:

```
employeeInfo *insert;
...
    head = insertHeadCircular(head, insert);
```

So you need to change one or the other.  Either dereference `insert` when you call the function from main, or change `insertHeadCircular()` to take a pointer instead (and update the body accordingly).  The latter is probably better, since it avoids copying the entire structure onto the stack when you call the function.

Some other things to point out:

You should really check the return from `scanf()` in your loop in `main()`.  It would let you know whether all the fields were actually read; right now, if they weren't, your program just proceeds with whatever junk the variables already had (like whatever was read on the previous iteration, possibly).  Checking other return values (like the return from `malloc()`) is a good idea too, but in this case the `scanf()` return is particularly important.

You also don't free `insert` at the end of your program; the OS will (almost certainly) clean it up when your program exits, but it's good practice to do it yourself when you're done with it.  The way you use it, though, you didn't really need to dynamically allocate it anyway; you could have just declared an `employeeInfo` and taken its address (works either way, though).

Comment: Alright, I edited my .h file heavily as per your recommendations, and the only remaining errors are in the .c file, where I call the functions. I'm still getting an error for insertHeadCircular.. `file.c::error: incompatible type for argument 2 of âinsertHeadCircularâ` ..so.. where I call it, `head = insertHeadCircular(head, insert);` it's saying that the struct that I've read in from the file is of incorrect type? what would be a better way of doing it?

Comment: @Flunkie The code you originally posted shouldn't have that particular error... check your changes.  Do you still have the prototype (but not the definition) for `insertHeadCircular()` in the header?  Is there a `*` missing in either the prototype or the definition's parameter list?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't change the `.c` at all, just the `.h`. The prototype I have is the same, `employeeList *insertHeadCircular(employeeList *head, employeeInfo emp);`

Comment: @Flunkie that's different from the prototype in your posted code, which has `employeeInfo *emp` instead of `employeeInfo emp`.  There are other problems with the code (besides what's causing the compiler errors), I may add some additional hints later.

Comment: Indeed it is. It was originally supposed to be without the `*` but changed it in a build right before my posting the problem here. Would it be helpful to see my code again after the changes? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The errors in the printing statements were caused by closing the main function before it got to them. Stupidest mistake I've ever made. The only remaining error is the incompatible types on line 37. The original post has been updated with my current program.